# Vectors and abstract classes

Tags: c++, vector, abstract-class

In SFML there are a few types of objects (sf::Shape, sf::Sprite, sf::Text) which inherit an abstract base class sf::Drawable. If I create an std::vector can I store all the objects which inherit the sf::Drawable class in that vector?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create objects of abstract classes, so you cannot store them in a vector. You can, however, store pointers to those objects in a vector.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a `std::vector` that stores some form of *pointer* (ideall a smart pointer) you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can if you declare a vector as

```
std::vector <sf::Drawable*>
```

any pointer on object based on this base class can be store in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

> If I create an std::vector can I store all the objects which inherit the sf::Drawable class in that vector?

Yes you can do that. You'll need a vector of pointers then (because you cannot instantiate abstract classes).