# Does C++ support abstract array lengths

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

If I have a base class `A` I would like to be able to write code in `A`that uses an array whose size is determined by its children

I want to be able to have an array of pointers to `A`, but I don't want to have a separate member function created for each length

The best I could come up with is as follows:

```
class A
{
   char type;
   int * values;
   int calc(int pos);  // implementation is not relevant to question
public:
   A (int * arr) : values(arr) {}
   int foo(int pos)
   {
      int index=calc(pos);
      return values[index];
   }
};

template <size_t X>
class B : public A
{
    int vals[X];
public:
    B() : A(vals) {}
};

template<>
class B<0>;  // don't want 0 allowed
```

This allows A to access an array where the child determines the size, and it is contiguous memory

But, it wastes the space of the `values` pointer and obfuscates information the compiler could use for optimization since as implemented it doesn't have to be contiguous memory that the child passes on construction, but I would like to require continuous memory.

Ideally I would like to use the offset directly in `A`

In `C` this works as `int values[]` but there is no `C++` equivalent

Comment: Could the base class be a template?

Comment: The code is just wrong. Pointer to an array is **not** a pointer to it's data type!

Comment: [std::vector<int>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) possibly?

Comment: If the memory allocated by `B` is not contiguous, how can `A` safely access individual members? For this to work, `B` should provide a getter with a prototype like `int& value_at(size_t offset)`.

Comment: It is also a terrible design to expect something from your child in your parent class - unless it's CRTP, which is not the case here.

Comment: Have a `std::vector` member in `A` and have derived classes call `A`'s constructor with a size.  Then `A` can initialize and hold on to an "array"(vector is a replacement to a raw array) where the size is determined by the derived class.

Comment: I tried to more descriptive in the question, the problem with `vector` is performance, not functionality, virtually wrapping the getters/setters in virtual funcs has a similar performance problem.

Comment: A vector should be just as fast as an array. Its basically the same thing. In fact its exactly the same thing on the inside.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum _"the problem with vector is performance"_ Rather use `std::array` then when possible. You have to draw a straw ...

Comment: A `vector` is a pointer to an array, compare it with `std::array` where it is contiguously allocated with other data members

Comment: By adding the pointer `values`in your example you have to dereference to get to your array producing the same situation provided with a vector.

Comment: yes, my question is how to avoid that, the difference though is locality

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, using templates:

```
template<std::size_t size>
struct A {
    A(std::array<int, size> _values) : values{_values} {}

private:
    std::array<int, size> values;
};

struct B : A<4> {
    using A<4>::A;
};
```

Then, you can use your class like this:

```
B myB{5, 6, 3, 2};
```

`std::array` allocates memory on the stack, or in the struct directly, just like a fixed array. You can test this by comparing sizes.

If you need a common base class, you can do this:

```
struct C {
    virtual ~C() {}
    virtual int* data();
    virtual std::size_t size();
};
```

And then overriting theses in `A`:

```
template<std::size_t size>
struct A : C {
    A(std::array<int, size> _values) : values{_values} {}

    int* data() override {
        return values.data();
    }

    std::size_t size() override {
        return size;
    }

private:
    std::array<int, size> values;
};
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but watch out what you call a stack. `new B()` is not putting `values` on the stack.

Comment: What I call the stack is the local stack, as declaring the size of `B` is affected by the array size.

Comment: One caveat to this is that subclasses will not share a common base class with other subclasses that use different sizes.

Comment: If `A` inherits from `C`,  then any instanciation of `A` or subclass of any `A` will share the common base class `C`.

Comment: I corrected the errors in my answer, thanks for pointing out, forgot the `: C {` in front of `A`

Answer (score 2):

The classic way to implement this is using inheritance and *virtual members*:

```
class A {
    virtual int& value_at(size_t pos);
    // other interesting methods
};

// subclass of A that uses std::vector for storage
class B: public A {
    std::vector<int> storage;
    int& value_at(size_t pos) {
        return storage[pos];
    }
};

// subclass of A that uses a fixed-size array for storage
template<int N>
class C: public A {
    int storage[N];
    int& value_at(size_t pos) {
        return storage[pos];
    }
};

B b;     // ...initialize b...
C<10> c; // ...initialize c...
A *a1 = &b;
A *a2 = &c;
// call a1->value_at(), a2->value_at() to access arrays
// transparently, regardless of storage (along with other
// public methods of A).
```

This approach will require `A::value_at` to dispatch via a virtual table or equivalent mechanism. If it is known at compile-time which storage strategy will be used, you can make `A` a template class:

```
template<typename T>
class A: public T {
    // other interesting methods, that use value_at() from T
};

class vec_storage {
    std::vector<int> storage;
public:
    int& value_at(size_t pos) {
        return storage[pos];
    }
};

// subclass of A that uses a fixed-size array for storage
template<int N>
class array_storage {
    int storage[N];
public:
    int& value_at(size_t pos) {
        return storage[pos];
    }
};

A<vec_storage> b;
A<array_storage<10>> c;
```

In this example, `b` and `c` will perform without the additional indirection at run-time, but at the cost that there is no generic base class, so a function expecting some `A &` cannot be passed a reference to either `b` or `c`.

Comment: Classic I'd disagree with, because this is rather inefficient. The design in the question is far more performant.

Comment: @MSalters It is more performant, but it doesn't satisfy the (stated) requirements - that the subclass may implement non-contiguous storage.

Comment: I tried to restate that part in the last, the goal is to allocate continuous storage

Answer (score -2):

For just the basic ability to change the size of the object's array, you're probably looking for *templates*, as Fred Larson pointed out. It's actually quite simple...

```
template <const int arraySize>
class MyClass
{
    private:
        int vals[arraySize];
}
```

At this point, you don't even need any derived classes. You're good to go, and can work with **any size** on the fly.

Bear in mind, however, that `MyClass` is not a valid type in this scenario. Because this is a template, you must specify the size.

```
MyClass wrong; //This will throw an error. MyClass is not a type.
MyClass<64> right; //This is a proper use of the type.
```

---

If you need the additional ability to store those objects of different sizes, you can combine this with inheritance fairly easily using a virtual [but **not abstract**] base class.

(Please ignore the crufty design, as I haven't bothered to define my constructors/destructors in this example.)

```
class BaseClass
{
    public:
        BaseClass(){}
        virtual int access(int i)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        virtual ~BaseClass(){}
};

template <const int arraySize>
class MyClass : public BaseClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(){}
        int access(int i)
        {
            return vals[i];
        }
        ~MyClass(){}
    private:
        int vals[arraySize];
};
```

> **WARNING:** It is critical that the base NOT be abstract if you want to be able to store your derived classes in a vector. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17708464/472647).

In this example, of course, you may want to create wrapper functions for accessing the array.

Comment: I have edited to meet that additional need. Sorry for overlooking that.