# Vector in an abstract class

Tags: c++, vector

I believe that the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708464/vectors-and-abstract-classes) is similar however I still need more clarification on it.

Let's say I create a vector inside an abstract class (which stores objects of another class). How would I be able to use .pushback() from another class if I can't initialise an object of an abstract class?

Obviously the easiest solution is to put the vector in another class but I need another way. I've read you can do this by storing pointers to those objects in a vector. But can somebody give me an example please?

Comment: The linked question is about storing instances of classes that inherit your abstract class in the vector... Is that what you want to do?

Comment: I want to store objects of one class in a vector that is in an abstract class. Normal way of doing it would be to create an object of that class then using .pushback() to that vector. But since you can't make an object of an abstract class,I can't do that

Comment: You will need another class that inherits from your abstract class to use it. That's the whole point of abstract classes.

Comment: You can't. You would have to derive a new class from the abstract class - That's the kind of polymorphic behaviour that abstract classes are intended for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of an abstract class is to provide an interface that is then implemented in concrete derived classes.

If you want to push items onto the vector which is a data member of the abstract class, then create an appropriate derived class and then you can  create an instance of that derived class, which will thus contain a vector you can add entries to.

```
class Base{
public:
  virtual void do_stuff()=0; // this is an abstract base class
protected:
  std::vector<int> data;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
  void do_stuff() {
    // concrete implementation
    data.push_back(42); // can add values to vector inherited from base class
  }
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
  d.do_stuff(); // will add entries to d.data
}
```

However, I wonder if that is really what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I could find some existing SO answers, but they were using C++98 code.

The *right* way to store a vector of abstract base classes, *in that base class* , is to have a vector of smart pointers to the abstract base class.

First, add the vector, and a virtual destructor

```cpp
struct AbstractBase {
    virtual ~AbstractBase(); // <-- this makes sure these shenanigans don't cause memory leaks
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase>> children;
};
```

Then push_back new derived classes:

```cpp
struct Derived1 : public AbstractBase; // defined elsewhere

/*...*/

base.children.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived1>());

//or

auto child = std::make_unique<Derived1>();
base.children.push_back(std::move(child));
```

It has to be a vector of pointers allocated on the heap because vector doesn't know from the base class how big the derived classes are to store them directly.

It has to be a vector of *smart pointers* because when you're using pointers and heap allocation, someone has to be responsible for cleaning them up. Smart pointers do that automatically.

Lastly, that virtual destructor there in the abstract base class makes sure that even when you're using pointers that have been casted down to abstract base classes, it will call the right destructor to clean everything up.